# SQL Agent Job retry attempts

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-agent-job

I created a SQL agent job and one of the step is to call a SSIS ETL package. 
In the SQL Server Agent Job steps, I saw there is a setting for 'retry attempts'.

May i know this is the setting to restart the specific step or it to process continue from where it failed previously?

My concern is on the ETL step. If it failed (for some reason), will the "retry attempt" pick up where it failed previously or it start the whole ETL process again?

Thanks.

Comment: This is the SQL Agent job setting for retrying. Your SSIS settings may be different. Feel free to test this but the agent will fire off the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My concern is on the ETL step. If it failed (for some reason), will the "retry attempt" pick up where it failed previously or it start the whole ETL process again?

If this step starts the ETL Process,then retrying this would restart entire ETL process.